# zsh shows git-status even tough it is not a repo

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use ZSH and I find it great.

However one thing about it confuses me:

If I'm working in a repo-folder then `zsh` shows the name of the repo and the git:(branch information). For example, something like this : `➜  my_repo git:(develop)`

But now my observation: Whenever I am in a non-git folder, the `zsh` Terminal still shows an arbitrary git:(branch information) - even tough there is no `.git` !! It sais, for example: `➜ my_non_git_fildername git:(develop)`

Why is the git(branch information) not dissappearing when I'm in a non-git folder ?

I use ["oh my zsh"](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) and I am working with the (git) plugin.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: How to use zsh and oh-my-zsh is not a programming question.

Comment: sorry @matt, I did not know where to ask else. You can configure zsh inside the .zshrc File and this comes to complexity asked in other Stackoverflow questions. So I felt I dare to ask. Also, zsh and oh-my-zsh where keywords that already exist - so other people must have asked about its usage before.

Comment: I would suggest trying SuperUser.

Comment: Try running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to see if you are unexpectedly in a repository.